# How to get UserAgent of OkHttp 4.x?

Tags: android, okhttp

In OkHttp 3.x, we can get the user agent using

```
import okhttp3.internal.Version

println(Version.userAgent())
```

However, this is not working anymore in OkHttp 4.x.

There was an issue raised in https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/5969, and fixed in https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/5981, but I can't get it to work.

In the change log, it is stated starting version 4.7.0.

```
New: Constant string okhttp3.VERSION. This is a string like “4.5.0-RC1”, “4.5.0”, or “4.6.0-SNAPSHOT” indicating the version of OkHttp in the current runtime. Use this to include the OkHttp version in custom User-Agent headers.
```

But I just can't get to import `okhttp3.VERSION`

Comment: Note that anything in the `internal` package is not intended to be public API and that using it is likely to not be backwards or forwards compatible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After clearing the cache and resync, I can now have the version

```
import okhttp3.OkHttp.VERSION

println(VERSION)
```